# Check if a route parameter exists in Laravel custom validation rule?

Tags: request, laravel-5.6

Consider the following URIs:

- `countries/{country}/persons/{person}/someAction`
- `cities/{city}/persons/{person}/anotherAction`

I do already have a rule `check_country_contains_person` working fine, but I should extend it to `check_group_contains_person` to be used in both method's validation classes.

---

Inside Validation Rule's `passes` function, how can I check if `request()->route('country')` and/or `request()->route('city')` are **available** or not?

Please note that if I were sure which one exists, I could do the rest.
That's just about checking availability of the route parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check existence of a route parameter in laravel just check this:

```
is_null($request->route('sample'))
```